# Hyperledger composer Redeploy Banana file

Tags: hyperledger-composer, redeploy

I have installed latest Hyperledger Composer 0.19.  Now with new version the command "composer network update" is not available.   Now I am not sure how to  redeploy changes in .BNA file to the network.  Can someone explain how "Composer network install" command can be used to redeploy incremental changes to .BNA file to the network

Answer (score 1):

This was changed as part of the native fabric deployment support added to Composer in 0.19.0. From the [0.19.0 release notes](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases/tag/v0.19.0):

> This release includes a fundamental change in the way that business
>   networks are deployed. Business networks are now deployed within
>   Hyperledger Fabric 'as chaincode' meaning that the business network
>   (rather than Composer runtime) can be agreed by all parties and
>   signed, using a similar management model to non-Composer chaincode. As
>   a result of this, the deployment and update process has changed.

You need to use the new [composer network upgrade](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/composer.network.upgrade.html) command instead:

> The commands to upgrade (update) a business network have changed and
>   are now:
>
> composer network install
>   composer network upgrade
>
> The following commands are no longer valid:
>
> composer runtime install
>   composer network deploy
>   composer network update
>   composer network undeploy

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the commands have changed for v0.19 of composer.

For each release there is a [releases document](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases) which covers the changes - so checking these when you upgrade is good.

When you first deploy your network you use the commands:

`composer network install` and

`composer network start`

and there are examples in the https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.

When you subsequently want to deploy a new version you use the commands:

`composer network start` and

`composer network upgrade`

There are examples of these in the [Queries tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/queries).

These new commands for Composer bring it more into line with the underlying Fabric now that it can use Native NodeJS chaincode.